# How to Save data in existing list view to SQLITE database and clear the list view for a new list

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am developing an android application for supermarket customers. There I want customer to add items to their shopping list. Once the customer done with the shopping list he can close the shopping list (Save to SQLite DB) to and Add a new shopping list. Each shopping list has a unique ID and a shopping list can contain many items.

I am using a code and There I know once user add an item  and click on ADD button it will be dispalyed in List View it will be saved to DB. And My problem is how can I provide user to save one shoppinglist with unique ID and Clear the existing shopping list and add a new shoppinglist?

Thankx

Comment: show your code what you did so far

Comment: actually you don't need to save the data of listview, you need to save the arraylist that you are using and for clear a listview first clear the arraylist like arraylist.clear(); and notify your adapter like this adapter.notifydatasetchanged();. For clear view provide your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a model class named ShoppingList and implement it so that it may contain all the required attribute for a shopping list along with the list of items, and list_id.
Make a new table in database for a shopping_list and put its primary key to be as integer and auto increment. this way when you will add a new list record to table its key will be incremented each time.

I would suggest you to put shopping items in a separate table and use refrential integrity as shopping list has items.

For a better Relational model as a shopping list can contain many items and an item can be in many shopping lists. So the relationship between shopping list and items becomes associative entity and it gets a separate table in database with foreign keys of shopping list and items.

Below diagram represents the core relationship that you will have to implement along with the other desired attributes in each table
[image]